# How to check what compression type an RPM package uses?

Tags: rpm, gzip, oracle-linux, xz

I recently realized that the RPM packages shifted from gzip-compression to xz-compression a few years ago. I need to check is the compression type of an RPM package that I have. I also need to check what compression type is considered by my system when it is trying to unpack an RPM file.

Comment: Since you're using oracle-linux you should have the script `/usr/lib/rpm/rpm2cpio.sh`  - this script works out what type of compression is used and will decompress it.  You can probably use that as the basis for checking the compression your rpm package uses.

Comment: How can I figure out the compression type with this?

Answer (score 10):

[Query](https://rpm-software-management.github.io/rpm/man/rpm.8.html#querying-and-verifying-packages) the RPM with a custom [format](https://rpm-software-management.github.io/rpm/manual/queryformat.html) that includes the [**Payloadcompressor**](https://rpm-software-management.github.io/rpm/manual/tags.html#packages-with-files) tag ("Payload compressor name") like this:

```bash
rpm -q --queryformat '%{PAYLOADCOMPRESSOR}\n' -p qt-4.8.7-67.fc36.x86_64.rpm
```

By the way other interesting tags are **Payloadflags** ("Payload compressor level") and **Payloadformat** ("Payload format (cpio)").

Answer (score 0):

If you use `rpm2cpio`; you don't need to know the compression format. You can use `rpm2cpio` to unpack rpms like this:

```
rpm2cpio your.rpm | cpio -idmv
```

Answer (score 0):

To address: *Which compression formats are supported?*

It's easy enough to see what's not supported, e.g. trying to install an RPM from Fedora 34 on RHEL 6:

```
$ rpm --install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/.../Packages/t/tzdata-2021a-1.fc34.noarch.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
        rpmlib(PayloadIsZstd) <= 5.4.18-1 is needed by tzdata-2021a-1.fc34.noarch
```

Although this dependency is not explicitly exposed by `rpm-libs` in a way which can be queried by `--whatprovides`, we can infer the compression formats supported by `rpm-libs`.

```
### why do all compression formats have "z" in the name? It's the fashion.
$ rpm -q --requires rpm-libs | grep '^lib.*z'
libbz2.so.1()(64bit)
liblzma.so.5()(64bit)
liblzma.so.5(XZ_5.0)(64bit)
liblzma.so.5(XZ_5.1.2alpha)(64bit)
libz.so.1()(64bit)
```

Another way to track this would be the features changes for Fedora etc.:

- Fedora 12, [switch to XZ](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/XZRpmPayloads)
- Fedora 31, [switch to zstd](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/Switch_RPMs_to_zstd_compression)